# Shorthand for local variable definition not returning anything

Tags: ruby, variables

I wanted to cut down on variable definitions in some code; especially those that just define an empty hash or array. The solution I found was this:

Original:

```
my_array = Array.new

0..10.each do |i|
  my_array << i
end
```

Redone version:

```
0..10.each do |i|
  ( my_array ||= Array.new ) << i
end
```

When I run both of them in the rails console the following happens: After running the original version I can access 'my_array', while with the redone version I can't...It's still undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: define `my_array = nil` before the loop, in the second solution

Comment: This would defeat its purpose?

Comment: You have to put parentheses around the range, i.e. `(0..10).each`.

Comment: `my_array = *0..10` is a concise way to do exactly what the code in OP does, but probably too far removed from real-world requirements to be a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example the variable `my_array` is local to the block, so it is not visible outside the block itself. For this kind of jobs I like to use the [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method:

```
my_array = (1..10).each_with_object([]) do |i, my_array|
  my_array << i
end

my_array
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally I find that if you have to declare an empty container and then run a loop to fill it with contents, then there's (almost) always a better way.

Here's an improved way to write your code:

```
my_array = (0..10).map do |i|
  i # do your complex processing here
end

my_array # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Also `my_array = Array.new(11) { |i| whatever_function(i) }`

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: I think it is the same as Sergio's answer (first sentence says what I'd want to say), just different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Because the scope of `my_array` in your modified version is only up to the block

Try defining a global variable instead

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > 
1.9.3-p448 :002 >   [*0..10].each do |i|
1.9.3-p448 :003 >     ( @my_array ||= Array.new ) << i
1.9.3-p448 :004?>    end
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
1.9.3-p448 :005 > @my_array
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
1.9.3-p448 :006 >
```

Using `@` variables in console gives a global scope

Comment: Are you advising using global mutable state? This is bad practice.

Comment: Considering scope is the only problem he need to fix. Anyway @toro2k's answer is better

Answer (score 1):

In this cases I like to use the [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method, which is more generic than `Enumerable#each_with_object`:

```
my_array = [].tap do |my_array|
  0..10.each { |i| my_array << i }
end
```